# How to activate Developer tab in Powerpoint 2010 programmatically?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, ribbon, office-interop, office-2010

Could anyone help me how can I activate the 'developer' tab on my Powerpoint2010 application?  I have created a new Powerpoint presentation

```
PowerPoint.Application oPPT = new PowerPoint.Application();
oPPT.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;

PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = oPPT.Presentations;
PowerPoint.Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

Now I just want to enable the Developer tab which by default is not disabled.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a setting for the PowerPoint application (for 2010) not a single presentation. As part of the ribbon I do not see a simple way to enable the developer tab. Probably, it could be done by customizing the ribbon.

However, the easiest way seems to be setting the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options\DeveloperTools = 1` before starting PPT.

Comment: Thanks Paul B. Though not exactly what I am looking for, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit, Paul's correct, you can (have to, in fact) add the developer tab by customizing the ribbon in 2010.

File | Options | Customize Ribbon and put a check next to "Developer" in the list box on the right.